# Choosing want over need

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

My husband often uses the word "need" when I would use "want".  When asked if he would like a drink he will say "No thanks, I don't need one right now".  Does the use of the word need instead of want give the response a different meaning?

Comment: The dictionary points out the subtly very significant difference between 'want' and 'need'.

Comment: In your example's case, your husband's desire ('want') could be based upon a purpose ('need') .  If he is in the habit of chosing whether to drink or not more as self-medication (when he's feeling tense, or bothered etc) he might see it more like a question relating to aspirin "Would you like an aspirin?"  In answering with "need" he might be showing his rational a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a drought or you were hiking through the Sahara with limited water supply, it would makes sense that your husband would use 'need'. But, if you are sitting down to dinner in your suburban split-level your husband should say 'want'.

> **need:**  a requirement, necessary duty, or obligation. ([Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/need))

> **want:**  have a desire to possess or do (something); wish for. ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/want))

Comment: It's important to mention the sources by name as far as possible. I've edited yours for now. :)

Comment: Thanks, @NVZ.  I appreciate it.  Will do that moving forward.

Comment: You are broadly correct in your answer. However, it is not a hard and fast distinction. Some people do, on occasion, say "need" when they mean "want". There is an area of overlap here.

Comment: The question is not whether people say 'need' when they mean 'want', but if they should.  I propose there is not a hard and fast distiction simply because people are lazy or unthinking--either way they are being imprecise.

Comment: This slightly rankles because *need* is typical (US) law enforcement-speak for *want*. No, you don't "need" for me to step over there, or show you ID, etc, but expressing it as a need places the citizen in an inferior position.

Comment: See my comment to the OP.  By using "need" the husband could be sending a signal that he only prefers to drink when the drink will serve a purpose, not merely as an indulgence or pleasure.

Comment: @JimMack  actually, I believe that when giving an order, "need" is the correct word.  Whether or not police "should" (or "when" and "where") have the authority to order civilians to take certain actions is a political and legal discussion, but when they're giving an order they aren't merely "wanting".